# Simulating r.v.'s $X, Y, X \in [0,1]: X+Y+Z = 1\;a.s.$ given we know $E[X],E[Y],E[Z]$ and $E[X]+E[Y]+E[Z]=1$ with marginal variances $\sigma^2$

Tags: simulation, random-generation, dirichlet-distribution

I think my title says most of my question, but let me re-state:

I am trying to simulate variable percentages (i.e., X,Y,Z) on the above simplex without using the Dirichlet distribution. The reason being that the Dirichlet can produce bi-modal distributions for the individual proportions, even though we know that the probability should be concentrated around the mean of each proportion in a unimodal way.

The difficulty I am having is honoring both the marginal expected values and the common marginal variance constraints.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of the simulation? Does the simulation distribution have to have positive density everywhere on the simplex? Do you intend that all marginal variances be the same, as suggested in the title?

Comment: We have a markov chain with variable transition probabilities. I need to allow a given row of proababilites to vary while (a) maintaining the sum to 1, and meeting pre-specified marginal means and a common marginal variance (all variances the same).

Comment: Good! But is that all you really know about the chain? And why is multi-modality a problem? (Incidentally, if that common variance is not too large compared to the squared means and their squared complements, even the Dirichlet distribution would not have multimodal marginals; and if the variances *are* too large, it may be the case that *no* distribution will exist with the desired properties.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will meet your need as it is too degenerate and symmetric, but just in case it might help I will present it. It is possible to do what you have asked in at least one case. For example, here is a construction using uniform marginals.

Generate $X \sim \mathrm{Unif} [0,{2 \over 3}].$
Set $$Y = \begin{cases} X+{1/3} \ , & \text{if} \ X \le {1/3} \\ X-{1/3} \ , & \text{if} \ {1/3} \lt X \le {2/3}  \end{cases}$$ Let $Z = 1 - X - Y.$

Then it's not too hard to show that $X,$ $Y,$ and $Z$ are identically distributed with 
$ \mathrm{Unif} [0,{2 \over 3}]$ distributions. Additionally (this might be where it won't work for you) the pairwise correlations are all $-{1 \over 2}$ and only one call to a uniform random generator is needed to get the three variates.

Comment: +1. Thanks. Yes, a little too coarse for my needs, but thanks for the good thoughts.